# KTOR: How I can find Location Info before call processing?

Tags: ktor

I made a custom feature that should check the user's permissions to use the request. Can I monitor request LocationInfo?
Can this looks like that?

```
if (!User.accessTo.contains(CALL_LOCATION_INFO)){
call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) }
```

That`s my feature code:

```
data class UserRights(
        val haveFullAccess:Boolean,
        val accessTo:List<String>,
        val canUpdate:Boolean,
        val canDelete:Boolean,
        val canBan:Boolean,
        val canMute:Boolean)

var User = UserRights(false, listOf(""),false,false,false,false)

class RightsChecker(configuration: Configuration) {
    val prop = configuration.prop // get snapshot of config into immutable property
    class Configuration {
        var prop = "value"
    }
    companion object Feature : ApplicationFeature<ApplicationCallPipeline, Configuration, RightsChecker> {
        override val key = AttributeKey<RightsChecker>("RightsChecker")
        override fun install(pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline, configure: Configuration.() -> Unit): RightsChecker {
            val configuration = RightsChecker.Configuration().apply(configure)
            val feature = RightsChecker(configuration)

            val FilterPhase = PipelinePhase("CallFilter")
            pipeline.insertPhaseAfter(ApplicationCallPipeline.Infrastructure, FilterPhase)

            pipeline.intercept(FilterPhase) {
                val session = call.sessions.get<SessionData>() ?: SessionData(0, "Guest")
                when (session.role) {
                    "Guest" -> User = UserRights(
                            haveFullAccess = false,
                            accessTo = listOf(""),
                            canUpdate = false,
                            canDelete = false,
                            canBan = false,
                            canMute = false)
                    "User" -> User = UserRights(
                            haveFullAccess = false,
                            accessTo = listOf("lUsers"),
                            canUpdate = false,
                            canDelete = false,
                            canBan = false,
                            canMute = false)                       
                    "Admin" -> User = UserRights(
                            haveFullAccess = true,
                            accessTo = listOf("lUsers"),
                            canUpdate = true,
                            canDelete = true,
                            canBan = true,
                            canMute = true)
                }
                if (!User.accessTo.contains(CALL_LOCATION_INFO)){
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                }
            }
            return feature
        }
    }
}
```

How you can see, I`m using UserRights data class with rights in it. "accesTo" - is list of location names (format can be changed) what user can use. Feature must just check location name contain in "accesTo" list before request processing.

Thank you for help!

UPD: Locations code:

```
@Location("/login") data class lLoginData(val email:String, val password: String)
@Location("/users") data class lGetUsers(val page:Int, val limit:Int)
@Location("/users/user") data class lUser(val email: String)
@Location("/users") data class lUpdateData(val userID: Int, val datatype:String, val newData:String)
@Location("/users") data class lRegData(val email: String, val username:String, val userpass:String)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you simply want to know what route / uri was called.

Here is a small server that answers with the route called.

private val locationKey = AttributeKey("location")

```
val module = fun Application.() {
    install(Routing) {
        intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
            val location = call.request.local.uri
            call.attributes.put(locationKey, location)
        }

        get("{...}") {
            val location = call.attributes[locationKey]
            call.respond(location)
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I am using `call.request.local.uri` to get the uri of the call.

When I navigate to `http://localhost:5001/hello/route`, the server answers with `/hello/route`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly what I need. I have different Locations in one URL. I need exactly Location info. (I added the @Location code to the post)

Comment: Can you explain what `CALL_LOCATION_INFO` could be ?

Comment: I found. "call.route.parent". looks like "/user/{user_id}" (URL looks like "/user/user_id=9572" for example)